# Does Websphere Liberty Profile support full Java EE 7 OR Servlet 3.1 Specification?

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am interested in using the Non-Blocking I/O features of Servlet Specification 3.1 like here http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/servlets013.htm#BEIHICDH

I can't find a definitive answer on IBM dev site whether JSR-340 is supported.

Does WAS LibertyProfile support Servlet Specification  3.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slide deck from Impact2013 said that WAS 8.5.5 is at servlet 3.0. The recent 8.5.5.next notes didn't mention anything about updating that.

This page from Oracle shows the certified servers:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html

If you care to look at any other servers, apart from glassfish the wildfly beta is reported to support servlet 3.1 (and Jave EE 7 in general) but I have no idea when to expect the release.

http://undertow.io/

Comment: Answer not correct anymore, see [Alex answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30744360/3701228)

Answer (score 2):

The version 8.5.5.4 supports Servlets 3.1 and WebSockets 1.0 and some other Java EE 7 specs, but not yet all. For latest information check this page [New Liberty features and tools](https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/blog/2014/12/09/announcing-new-liberty-features-tools/)

Answer (score 2):

New update.. WAS Liberty 8.5.5.5 (March 2015) supports several Java EE7 technologies (for production use) including Servlet 3.1 and Websocket 1.1.  Announced today is the full Java EE7 stack for Liberty which will be available on 26th June.

Comment: Alex, maybe add info that Beta with full support is already available if someone is very keen to use it ;)

Comment: Ooh good point, here's the beta link: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/downloads/liberty-profile-beta/

Answer (score 0):

No, it only supports Servlet 3.0.  See the [Programming model support](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_prog_model_support.html) page in the 8.5 InfoCenter.

Comment: Answer not correct anymore, see [Alex answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30744360/3701228)

Answer (score 0):

update, they have a beta out

https://www.ibmdw.net/wasdev/2014/03/28/announcing-websphere-application-server-beta/

it has some java ee 7 but no servlet 3.1 yet

Comment: Answer not correct anymore, see [Alex answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30744360/3701228). And current (June 2015) beta have full Java EE 7